# 2 filtros em BindingSource no vb

Tags: vb.net

Eu possuo um datagridview de funcionarios e consigo filtra-los atraves do nome de cada funcionario atraves deste codigo:

```
FuncionariosBindingSource.Filter = "nome like'%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
```

Neste mesmo datagridview possuo uma coluna "ano" que é marcado a entrada do funcionario, gostaria de saber se tem como eu filtrar o nome e o ano do funcionario. Por exemplo no textbox1 digita "Joao" e no textbox2 (Referente ao ano) digita 2015, ai só aparecia o Joao de 2015.

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia Mateus, você terá que criar outro campo pra inserir o ano e no evento que faz a busca você usa o campo do ano pra filtrar. Tem um exemplo no link abaixo que esta bem explicado.

http://www.macoratti.net/09/04/c_dtb1.htm

Comment: Entendi mais ou menos esse link, minha dificuldade esta para adaptar, porque pelo site que voce passou esta em c# e estou usando visual basic e nao estou conseguindo encaixar esse codigo. Tentei assim : `FuncionariosBindingSource.Filter = "nome like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' AND ano = " + TextBox2.Text ` e nao deu certo

Comment: Agora consegui com esse codigo aqui: `FuncionariosBindingSource.Filter = "nome LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' and ano LIKE '%" + TextBox2.Text + "%'"`   Valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: O link era mais pra você ter uma noção mesmo de como fazer... Fico feliz por ter conseguido.